# Protractor - first it block always fails by giving some misleading error

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I have written protractor test for angular application with non angular login page. So i have added that login in separate login file with `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);`

And then added describe block with series of it blocks to test the application.
Whenever i run the first it block always failed. I have then deleted the body and run. Here also it fails with some misleading error `- NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="Username"])`

This error is actually relates with the login feature. But at that point it has successfully passed. What is the reason behind this issue ?

My code Structure is

```
 describe("Test Cases in first feature ", () => {
      //login via non angular application
      login.SignIn(settings.usercredentials.LocalUser.userName, settings.usercredentials.LocalUser.password);

      it("dummy tc", () => {

      });

     it("New Mission Creation", () => {
 main_dashboard_page.newItem("mission");
 });
```

Comment: add the login inside the it, and add 'function' before '()', something like
    it('1-Should Login', function() {
        //Login;
    });

Answer (score 1):

Code not contained with an it block will not be executed in the order you expect and any issues generated by that code will also not be handled as you would normally expect either. Your login function code will run before any other code on the page and that is likely that cause of your issue. For a login function such as this it is recommended to have it contained within the beforeAll or beforeEach (or it's own it).

I have a similar application with a non-angular login and am handling it in the following manner (using async/await syntax)

```
beforeAll(async function () {
    //before any tests run we want to launch the URL and log in

    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    await loginPO.loginToApplication(browser.params.login.username, browser.params.login.password, browser.params.loginSite.url);

    //I create some additional logic to ensure login was successful before re-enabling angular wait
    await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
});
```

**Non async/await approach**

```
beforeAll(function () {
    //before any tests run we want to launch the URL and log in

    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    loginPO.loginToApplication(browser.params.login.username, browser.params.login.password, browser.params.loginSite.url);

    //I create some additional logic to ensure login was successful before re-enabling angular wait
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
});
```

**Updated Answer:**

```
it('login before tests execute', () => {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    loginPO.loginToApplication(browser.params.login.username, browser.params.login.password, browser.params.loginSite.url);

    //You can create additional logic to ensure login successful
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
})
```

Comment: Thanks @DublinDev for your  response. I also tried with this beforeAll. But in my case i have few spec files and if i put such before all for each of these specs then all of the Before all methods run very first and mess the order of test execution. do you have any idea on how to solve such issue ?

Comment: Just to clarify, beforeAll can be used so that it will effect a single file (placed within specific spec files) or effect all files (placed in the config). For the file (or files) it affects it will be triggered before every Describe block. So by placing it in a spec file it should only cause issues if you have multiple describes in a single spec file. If you do have such a setup you could potentially but the login functionality in it's own it block but it will need to be contained somewhere for sure

Comment: Also I've added a non async/await style for you as I can see that is what you are using but I would recommend changes for framework over when you get a chance

Comment: Thnks for the detailed information. Actually i do have both cases. 1) Spec file with only one Describe block 2) Spec file with multiple Describe Blocks.

Comment: Ok In the case where you have multiple describes you can add a separate IT block that contains the login functionality. This will need to be placed before any of the other IT blocks. I have updated my answer with what I am referring to so could you give it a try and let me know